# Getting Facebook page access token only for app admin

Tags: facebook, live-streaming, facebook-page, facebook-access-token

I have a livestreaming (consumer) app with an associated Facebook page, and my goal is to broadcast streams from my app onto my Facebook page (live).

I have understood that part of the process to do this is getting a page access token from an admin of the page (like myself), who has granted my app the `pages_read_engagement` and `pages_manage_posts` permissions (which I have not done). However, in order to request those permissions, it seems like I would have to change the status of my app in Facebook (from being a consumer app), add those permissions, and undergo app review, even though I only want to request those permissions from a specific user. (This particular method is also not possible, since I already have 200,000+ users actively using my app.)

So my question is, how can I get a Facebook page access token for only a specific user of a specific page?

Comment: You would need to submit your app for review, before you can ask any normal user of your app for the relevant permissions. Users with a role in your app can be asked for permissions before review already though - so if you could add that specific user account as an admin/developer/tester of your app, you should be able to ask them for those permissions. (They would have to register their account as a developer first though, I think.) Whether everything fully works then though, you'd have to test.

Comment: If the chosen app type does not allow you to request those permissions in the first place though, then I don't think there is any other way than to create a separate app.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I have the user registered as an admin (it is a developer account). However, my app has already undergone app review without the necessary permissions (the app is already 3 years old), and I don't want to change the app for the current users. If I make a separate app though, could I get the page access token through that and then use it with my current app?

Comment: Theoretically you could use the access token with a different app, but I don't know if everything will work as expected then - you'd really have to test it. User-IDs are app-scoped, but everything else isn't AFAIK.

Comment: Okei cool, I'll have to try that! Thanks so much!!